# Conditioning argument for probability generating functions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, generating-functions

> Suppose $N\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda>0$, and $Y\sim Bin(N,p)$ for $0<p<1$. Further suppose $X\sim Poisson(Y+1)$. I want to find the PGF of $G_Y(z)$ and that $Y\sim Poisson(\lambda p)$

My idea is to use a conditioning argument. $G_Y(z)=\mathbb{E}[z^Y]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[z^Y|N=n]\mathbb{P}(N=n)$. But I'm not sure how to  solve this sum.

For $\mathbb{E}[z^Y|N=n]$, we can say that this is the PGF of a $Poisson(\lambda)$ random variable, which is $e^{n(z-1)}$, and for $\mathbb{P}(N=n)$ since$N\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ we have $\mathbb{P}(N=n)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!}$. So I *think* that the sum is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{n(z-1)}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!}$. I'm not sure how to find an explicit form for this sum, even though I wish for it to be $e^{n(\lambda p-1)}$ as this is the PGF of a $Poisson(\lambda p)$ random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}z^Y&=\mathsf{E}\!\left[\mathsf{E}[z^Y\mid N]\right]=\sum_{n\ge 0}(1-p+pz)^n\times\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n}{n!} \\
&=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(\lambda(1-p+pz))^n}{n!}=e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda(1-p+pz)} \\
&=e^{\lambda p(z-1)},
\end{align}
which is the PGF of $\text{Poisson}(\lambda p)$.

Comment: Thanks! Now if I wanted to find the PGF of $X$, how would I go about this? Since we have to condition on $Y$ aswell, this seems quite tough

Comment: @turtle Use the same idea. The result relies similarly on Taylor's series of the exponential function.

Comment: The difference here is that we are conditioning further - if we use the same method as for the first question we would have $\mathbb{E}[z^X]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[z^X|N]]=\sum_{n\ge 0}e^{Y+1(z-1)}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!}$, but since we have $Y$ in this expression I don't know what to do

Comment: @turtle111 You need to replace $Y$ with $n$ in the summation, i.e.
$$
\mathsf{E}[z^X]=\mathsf{E}[\mathbb{E}[z^X|N]]=\sum_{n\ge 0}e^{(n+1)(z-1)}\frac{e^{-\lambda p}(\lambda p)^n}{n!}.
$$

Comment: In this instance the sum would be $e^{z-p\lambda -1}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(p\lambda e^z)^n}{n!}e^{nz}$; I can't see how to evaluate this

Comment: $$
\sum_{n\ge 0}e^{(n+1)(z-1)}\frac{e^{-\lambda p}(\lambda p)^n}{n!}=e^{z-1-\lambda p}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(\lambda pe^{z-1})^n}{n!}.
$$

Comment: Apparently the mean of $X$ is $1+p\lambda$. This sum above would be $e^{p\lambda e^{z-1}+z-1-p\lambda}$. Is this correct? We require $G_X'(1)=1+\lambda p$

Comment: That's correct.